# Grouping by street address and splitting it into street name and number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains the following fields:

- building guid (`abcd-efgh-5678-1234`, `...`, etc)
- street address (`1256 Grant St`, `500 wall st`, etc)
- price (`$5000`, `$10000`, etc)

Based on this, I want to **add two new columns** to my `DataFrame` object in Pandas.:

- street name (`wall st`)
- street number (`500`)

Until now, I've been able to fetch specific instances of the word `wall st` as follows:

```
str_street = 'Wall St'
wall_st  = dataset.loc[dataset['street_address'].str.lower().str.endswith(str_street.lower()), :]
wall_st['street_name'] = ???
wall_st['street_address_number'] = ???
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'street address': ['500 wall street', '123 blafoo']})
print (df)
    street address
0  500 wall street
1       123 blafoo

df1 = df['street address'].str.extract('(?P<number>\d+)(?P<name>.*)', expand=True)
print (df1)
  number          name
0    500   wall street
1    123        blafoo
```

Solution with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[['number','name']] = df['street address'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
print (df)
    street address number         name
0  500 wall street    500  wall street
1       123 blafoo    123       blafoo
```

Comment: I like the regex approach. Is there a standard address regex I could use?

Comment: you can check [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings), but for regex need another sources like [python re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'street address': ['500 wall street', '123 blafoo']})
df['street address'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(None, 1)))
```

will result in:

```
     0            1
0  500  wall street
1  123       blafoo
```

You can then just rename the columns and `pd.concat` this to you original data frame.